# Running hg convert on Linux

Tags: linux, mercurial, perforce, mercurial-convert

I would like to convert a remote [Perforce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforce) repository into a [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) repository on Linux.
So I have installed Python and Mercurial on a Linux box.

Then I test few hg (Mercurial's drive program) commands. **All are working fine**.

Now without creating any hg repository on the Linux box I want to run `hg convert` on Linux, so that a Mercurial repository (of a Perforce repository) will be created on it.

But when I tried the "hg convert" command it was not working. I know "convert" extension needs to be configured in the .hgrc file. But I don't have any hg repositories here.

> Is there any any place on Linux where
>   I can create **hgrc file** with convert
>   extension so that hg convert command will be
>   accessible for me?
>
> or
>
> Should I first create a **hg init
>   hgrepo** on Linux and then edit .hg/hgrc file with
>   proper configurations and then perform
>   **hg convert //perforce repo/.. /root/hgrepo** on hgrepo?

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your .hgrc in your home directory, see the manual: [hgrc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html)

Comment: Thanks, I am able to do hg convert now.